# How do I parser multiple lines in RPLY?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I'm trying to create a fictional language using RPLY and i'm having troubles when i try to parse more than one line of my language.

I've searched and I found that my problem is in the grammar of the language. But I'm not too experienced with RPLY and I'm stuck with that problem.

I'm not able to construct in the parser.py file the right code (what function to call when defining the grammar rule)

I saw suggestions like create a rule `'program : program statement'` and `'program : statement'` but how do i define the function below for the rules above?

**AST.py**

```
class Integer():
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor

    def eval(self):
        return int(self.valor)
    
class OpBinarios():
    def __init__(self, esquerda, direita):
        self.esquerda = esquerda
        self.direita = direita

class Subtracao(OpBinarios):
    def eval(self):
        return self.esquerda.eval() - self.direita.eval()

class Soma(OpBinarios):
    def eval(self):
        return self.esquerda.eval() + self.direita.eval()

class Mult(OpBinarios):
    def eval(self):
        return self.esquerda.eval() * self.direita.eval()

class Div(OpBinarios):
    def eval(self):
        return self.esquerda.eval() / self.direita.eval()

class Mod(OpBinarios):
    def eval(self):
        return self.esquerda.eval() % self.direita.eval()

class Left_Shift(OpBinarios):
    def eval(self):
        return self.esquerda.eval() << self.direita.eval()

class Right_Shift(OpBinarios):
    def eval(self):
        return self.esquerda.eval() >> self.direita.eval()

class Unsigned_Right_Shift(OpBinarios):
    def eval(self):
        return (self.esquerda.eval() % 0x100000000) >> self.direita.eval()

class And(OpBinarios):
    def eval(self):
        return self.esquerda.eval() and self.direita.eval()

class Write(OpBinarios):
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
    
    def eval(self):
        print(self.valor.eval())
```

**parser.py**

```
def parse(self):
        @self.pg.production('program : WRITE OPEN_PAREN expression CLOSE_PAREN SEMI_COLON')
        def write(p):
            return Write(p[2])

        @self.pg.production('expression : expression SOMA expression')
        @self.pg.production('expression : expression SUBTRACAO expression')
        @self.pg.production('expression : expression MULT expression')
        @self.pg.production('expression : expression DIV expression')
        @self.pg.production('expression : expression MOD expression')
        @self.pg.production('expression : expression LEFT_SHIFT expression')
        @self.pg.production('expression : expression RIGHT_SHIFT expression')
        @self.pg.production('expression : expression >>> expression')
        def operacoes(p):
            esquerda = p[0]
            direita = p[2]
            operator = p[1]

            if operator.gettokentype() == 'SOMA':
                print()
                return Soma(esquerda, direita)
            
            elif operator.gettokentype() == 'SUBTRACAO':
                return Subtracao(esquerda, direita)
            
            elif operator.gettokentype() == 'MULT':
                return Mult(esquerda, direita)
            
            elif operator.gettokentype() == 'DIV':
                return Div(esquerda, direita)
            
            elif operator.gettokentype() == 'MOD':
                return Mod(esquerda, direita)

            elif operator.gettokentype() == 'LEFT_SHIFT':
                return Left_Shift(esquerda, direita)
            
            elif operator.gettokentype() == 'RIGHT_SHIFT':
                return Right_Shift(esquerda, direita)

            elif operator.gettokentype() == '>>>':
                return Unsigned_Right_Shift(esquerda, direita)
            else:
                raise AssertionError('Opa, isso não é possível!')
        
        @self.pg.production('expression : INTEGER')
        def numero(p):
            return Integer(int(p[0].value))
        
        @self.pg.error
        def error_handler(token):
            raise ValueError(f'Encontrou um {token.gettokentype()} onde não era esperado')

    def get_parser(self):
        return self.pg.build()
```

Some part of the code are in portuguese cuz I'm brazilian, if someone doesn't understand something, let me know.

Comment: Others will be able to help you better if yo include more code that shows what you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some guidance. Please read that and update your question. Thanks!

Comment: It depends what action you want. Perhaps you don't need any action, in which case you could just `pass`. More likely you need to construct an AST for the program, in which case you would want to add the AST for the statement to the AST you are building for the program. Or perhaps you are directly creating three-address instructions, or something similar.

Comment: show minimal working code and example data which we could simply copy and run - to see problem and test ideas.

Comment: @rici i'm building a AST. I'd like to know how am I gonna build the AST function to the Program too (how to define the 'main' body for my language on the AST.py).
I'll edit the question to show how my AST.py is set

Comment: @furas ok, i'll edit the question with some code

Comment: done. Question edited.